# What is the function of the given IC?

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, microchip

[image]
Which Type of IC is this one ? what is its function

Comment: Sounds like one of those proprietary parts that one can never get the datasheet for.

Comment: Nice picture. Where did you get it?

Comment: Add more information to your question, Basil. Where did you find it? Do you have any circuit of it? really yourself take picture of it or you just find it?

Comment: Judging by the SDIP-42 package, probably a microcontroller or perhaps memory, and possibly aimed at the Asian market. The _04 may be 4MHz or 40ns. However, that's just a guess- that and $2.50 will get you a coffee.

Comment: I believe the main function of this chip is to cause puzzled electrical engineers and generate traffic for google :-)

Comment: @gwideman Very cool! LoL!

Comment: @DaveTweed I found this IC from an electronics shop. I am trying to make a full database of different IC's. I took its photo using canon EOS 70D camera

Comment: So, what did the shop say the IC was for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a type of system Chip for Cathode Ray Tube Monitors. Now a days these DMO Series IC are not available. But in some Asian Markets it is still available